# Php selecting specific columns using WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I am aware this is somehow a noobish question, and I already knkow one option of solving it, but still. I have a database and a search form. What I am trying to accomplish is filter rows specific to what user sends me VIA post. I know how to get POST to my php variables, what I am trying to accomplish now is use variable as criteria only if it is not null. So something in the lines of>

```
SELECT * FROM db 
WHERE COL1=ifnotnull($variable from post form)
AND COL@ = ifnotnull($anothervariable)
.
.
.
```

So I want to include in my search only fileds from form which were entered (i.e. are not null)

I am aware this could be done via preprocessing all variables and checking if they are null and then not using them in SQL query, but is there a shorter way doing this on the fly with SQL?

I hope this I explained it thoroughly,

thanks.

Comment: Alright, thanks for answering to this.

Comment: theoretically, if the form fields are named the same as the table columns then you could build the entire query dynamically but it is risky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider *preprocessing all variables* as the most preferable approach. But here is tricky solution just for your case. (with *mysql user defined variables*):

```
...
$dbh = new PDO(...);   // a PDO instance representing a connection to a database
$var1 = 0;   // sanitized variable from POST array
$var2 = "pen";  // sanitized variable from POST array

$dbh->exec("SET @var1 := $var1; ");
$dbh->exec("SET @var2 := '$var2'; ");

// replace 'id' and 'name' with your column names
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (id = @var1 OR @var1 = '') AND (name = @var2 OR @var2 = '') ");
$stmt->execute();
....
```

Such approach takes into account all passed variables which are not empty

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. Great stuff.